# pip install from AWS CodeArtifact errors with 'No matching distribution found' when running in a docker build in a Jenkins pipeline, but works locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, dockerfile

I'm trying to pip install a package published AWS CodeArtifact during a docker build running in a Jenkins pipeline. I've loosely followed some of the examples offered by AWS [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/codeartifact-jenkins-python-sample/blob/master/application_src/Jenkinsfile)
Running a similar docker build in my local terminal works fine, but the same build in Jenkins fails.
Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9-minimal:9.1.0-1793

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=python39
ARG CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN
RUN microdnf install -y ${PYTHON_VERSION}

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN python -m venv /usr/app/venv
ENV PATH="/usr/app/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip config set global.extra-index-url "https://aws:$CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN@{xxxxx}.d.codeartifact.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/pypi/{REPO}/simple/"

RUN pip install package_in_repo
```

The token is retrieved and passed to the docker build command during the Jenkins pipeline:

```
authToken = sh(
                        returnStdout: true,
                        script: 'aws codeartifact get-authorization-token \
                        --domain {DOMAIN}  \
                        --domain-owner {OWNER} \
                        --region {REGION} \
                        --query authorizationToken \
                        --output text \
                        --duration-seconds 900'
                        ).trim()
image = docker.build("{ECR/REPO}:${TAG}", "--build-arg CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN='$authToken' --network host .")
```

Building the Docker image locally is fine, but through Jenkins it complains that the package can't be found:

```
#13 [builder 6/8] RUN pip install package_in_repo
#13 0.914 Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://aws:****@{domain}.d.codeartifact.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/pypi/{REPO}/simple/
#13 1.235 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package_in_repo (from versions: none)
#13 1.236 ERROR: No matching distribution found for package_in_repo
```

It seems Jenkins has access to the repo, as I don't get the 401 error, but can't see/find the package there

I was expecting the package would install fine through Jenkins. I checked:

- that the package does exist in the repo (again, can build the image locally and can pip install it directly locally)
- that Jenkins has AWS permissions (it uses a role that includes AWSCodeArtifactAdminAccess, so don't anticipate that being the problem)

I've tried different authentication attempts, e.g. login to CodeArtifact in the docker build with the cli, and passing a token from Jenkins, have tried specifying particular version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Realised issue shortly after - wasn't clear to me only the Repo owner has access to packages in the repo, I had to set the CodeArtifact repo policy to allow access from Jenkins (it worked locally for me as I was the owner of the repo)